# jQuery Migration. No equivalent to "then"

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

Hi I have been working on updating jQuery from 1.11 to 3.3.
I installed jQuery migration script which pointed out many of the differences that needed to be made. However, I have found no alternatives to this issue.

I have a callback in the "then" function that is not run immediately (synchronous), so I searched in the [guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#callback-invocation)! it recommends you to convert it to a callback to "done". However, the intention is different, I want to concatenate the promises not use the original promise.
I would use "pipe" but it has been [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/)! in favor of "then" so what do I use to keep the sync and at the same time be able to concatenate promises?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'd have to update to jQuery 2.x first, because the migration plugin works well for upgrading 1 major version at time, and the latest migration plugin is suited to upgrading from 2.x to 3.x...

Comment: Hi @CristianPorto, yes I did the migration in 2 steps using the guides in https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/